# Run /etc/profile.d/script.sh as root

Tags: permissions, startup, etc

I have script in `/etc/profile.d/script.sh` that contains 3 lines:

```
ifconfig ens5f5 down
hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ifconfig ensf5f
```

I need to run this script as root when any of users log in.

Here is written that all scripts in `/etc/profile.d/script.sh` are executed as root: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997365/execute-scripts-in-etc-profile-d-at-startup-as-root

I believe it's not true for Ubuntu 18.04 because I am getting errors due lack of permissions.

If you do not understand those commands, I am trying to permanently change MAC address. I know, that correct way would be to change file `/etc/network/interfaces`, but I had enough of trouble configuring that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/profile*` scripts do not run as root. Those scripts should be sourced by the login shell running under your user instead.

However, as you mentioned, your script approach is not a good way to change the MAC address. I'll describe a possible solution to get the script to work at the end anyway.

Ubuntu since 17.10 uses `netplan` to configure networking, which ignores the `/etc/network/interfaces` file used by the old `ifupdown`. Netplan is configured in `/etc/netplpan/01-netcfg.yaml` instead. Its content could look like this for an interface with overridden MAC address:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      macaddress: 12:34:56:78:AB:CD
      dhcp4: true
```

Also see the documentation for the `macaddress` configuration key in https://netplan.io/reference#common-properties-for-all-device-types

---

You could allow everyone to run a script with these commands as root using passwordless `sudo` - make sure you follow these steps correctly, otherwise you may end up with a broken `sudo` command or a privilege escalation vulnerability:

- Put your three commands in a separate script file (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/mac-change.sh`). Make sure it is safe to run this script as root at any time.
- Make that file owned by the root user (`sudo chown root: /usr/local/bin/mac-change.sh`)
- Set appropriate permissions: executable by everyone, writable only by the owner, root (`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/mac-change.sh`)
- Edit your sudoers file to allow everyone to run just that single script as root without password, by typing `sudo visudo` to open the sudoers editor and adding this line below near the bottom of the file:

  ```
  ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/mac-change.sh
  ```

Now everyone should be able to run `sudo mac-change.sh` or `sudo /usr/local/bin/mac-change.sh` without having to enter their password. You can then include this as a line in `/etc/profile` or a new script in `/etc/profile.d`.